# Using stock node js package installer for OS X, global NPM bower path not recognized

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, bower

I have installed nodejs with the package installer for OS X, which comes with NPM. The installation for NPM packages seems to be in `/Users/victorstan/.node`. After successfully installing Bower with `npm install -g bower`, it fails to let me execute bower:

`bower
 bash: bower: command not found`

How do I get globally installed packages to be properly installed?

Comment: Is `/Users/victorstan/.node/bin` in your `PATH`? What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Can you add that as the answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `/Users/victorstan/.node/bin` is in your `PATH`. Execute the following command:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you can't see that path in the list, you need to add it. Open `/Users/victorstan/.bash_profile` (or create it if doesn't exist) and add this line:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```